# Git merge 2 new file with removed content and added content

Tags: git, git-merge

So we are working in with 2 different repositories and both designers modified the same file.

the problem is quite simple but I have no ideas how to solve it yet. Both files are marked as new since they have almost nothing in common except that file.

When I try to merge from branch A to B it mark the parts added in A deleted in B and on the other side, what was added in B appears deleted in A.

git seems to try to outsmart me when I know that I need almost every changes and nothing should be mark as deletion.

I have 2 other branch that should merge without problem after these 2 branch. I can't merge them yet since there are some recent changes that may not merge really well too.

I have to merge A and B => E then C and D => F and then hopefully E and F

So the big question here is how can I do a completely manual merge that will mark every changes as conflict anything deleted anything added should be marked as conflict that I can solve by myself using an editor.

Git is trying to outsmart me and fail terribly at it.